# Function malfunction

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions, pass-by-value

The **main()** function code is supposed to call a function **blah(int,int)**   the code apparently stops responding after the second input is taken. It doesn't even go to the printf()but in case the function call is commented out 
the function performs the previous step of printing the values `printf()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

float ressil(int);
void blahh(int,int);
int common(int,int);

void main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("aaa");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("next");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("asd %d %d",a,b);

    blahh(a,b);
}

void blahh(int c,int d)
{
    printf("entered");
    int i=2;
    while(1)
    {
        if((float)ressil(i)<(float)(c/d))
        {
            printf("%d",i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure it hangs in the while loop, since `i` never changes.

Comment: Try adding `\n` at the end of your `printf` strings.

Comment: ...and you don't need to cast ressil() to float, it already is one. And you probably want `(float)c/d` instead of `(float)(c/d)`...since the latter does truncating integer division first.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your program so you see what’s actually going on.

Comment: Please add a minimal version of `ressil()` that still shows the error.

Comment: If an output like `printf("entered");` doesn't include an end-of-line `'\n'` it will commonly not be shown because the output is line-buffered. But actually `printf()` *is* executed. Your programm keeps spinning in the loop.